# Rewrite appended port number via Nginx

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, nginx, reverse-proxy

Hi I use Nginx as Reverse Proxy for Gunicorn and for Apache. Certain Subdomains are getting redirected to Gunicorn and everything else to Apache.
Also Nginx rewrites all http requests to https requests.

The first call usually works but with every interaction with an Apache-Site the listening port of Apache is added and this breaks my setup.
Everything non-Apache related works just fine.

What causes this behaviour and how can I fix it? Is it some Apache setting or is my nginx setup wrong?

```
    # everything to apache
    location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8090;
            proxy_set_header X-Nginx-Proxy true;
            }
```

Should I just rewrite every request with :8090 in it? What would the regex look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem is simply an external redirect (3xx status response) originating from Apache or the application hosted by Apache, then `nginx` is capable of rewriting it by using the `proxy_redirect` directive. You would need to study the exact content of the `Location:` response header, but one of these might be close:

```
proxy_redirect http://example.com:8090/ /
proxy_redirect https://example.com:8090/ /
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_redirect) for details.

If the problem is embedded URLs within the actual document (such as JS, CSS and images) then it needs to be fixed within the hosted application itself.

Comment: The proxy redirect did the job - thanks and happy hollidays